# SQL Server : find duplicates row with NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I need to find duplicate rows in a SQL Server table. The problem is that values may be NULL. I have the following code which seems to work fine as far as cells are not NULL:

```
select s.ID, t.* 
from [Data] s
join (select Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4, count(*) as cnt
      from [Data]
      group by Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4
      having count(*) > 1) t on s.Term1 = t.Term1 
                             and s.Term2 = t.Term2 
                             and s.Term3 = t.Term3 
                             and s.Term4 = t.Term4
```

How can I adapt it making it able find duplicates even if there are NULL values, such as

```
Term1    Term2    Term3    Term4
--------------------------------
hello    NULL     okay     NULL
hello    NULL     okay     NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `COUNT(*) OVER()`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Term1, Term2, Term3, Term4) AS cnt
  FROM [Data]
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: This is amazing!

Comment: What @LukaszSzozda is hinting at is that we're glad you found your answer, so please take a moment to mark this as your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer box. It lets other users know the question has an answer, and rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.